# Get current namespace with elisp

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to build a fn that generates a mock from a schema.

Once connected to the REPL in a Clojure project, I want to be able to generate a mock from a Plumatic schema. I'm using a lib that does that already and it's working. The only problem is it only works if I qualify the symbol with the project namespace. For instance, if the symbol-at-point is User which is in namespace contact.models, I need to concat these so that I pass "contact.models/User" to gen/generate.

Also, If I add the namespace by hand the eval works, but it does not print to the REPL. How do I do that?

```
(defun generate-mock ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((sym (symbol-at-point))
         (require-code "(require '[my-lib.generator :as gen])")
         (generate (concat "(gen/generate " (symbol-name sym) ")")))
    (cider-nrepl-sync-request:eval require-code)
    (cider-nrepl-sync-request:eval generate)))
```

Comment: There is no namespace in emacs-lisp. Can you please provide an example of input and actual vs. desired output?

Comment: @Trevoke Once connected to the REPL in a Clojure project, I want to be able to generate a mock from a Plumatic schema. I'm using a lib that does that already and it's working. The only problem is it only works if I qualify the symbol with the project namespace. For instance, if the symbol-at-point is User which is in namespace contact.models, I need to concat these so that I pass "contact.models/User" to gen/generate.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Put all relevant info in the question, not just in comments. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the namespace with `cider-current-ns`.

```lisp
(defun generate-mock ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((sym (symbol-at-point))
         (current-ns (cider-current-ns))
         (require-code "(require '[my-lib.generator :as gen])")
         (generate (concat "(gen/generate " current-ns "/" (symbol-name sym) ")")))
    (cider-nrepl-sync-request:eval require-code)
    (cider-nrepl-sync-request:eval generate)))
```

Comment: Please don't pose additional questions in your answer. One question per post, one answer per post, please.